# Can't import csv file into a table

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to import data from csv file into a table. I created the table using MySQL Workbench. Here is the command I enter in MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/db/test.csv' 
INTO TABLE info 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

But I am getting this error from MySQL:

```
Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar. 0.000 sec
```

Where and how to add the database name?

Comment: The error message is rather clear. MySQL does not know into which table the data needs to be loaded. You may try specifying the database as a prefix to the table name, something like `MyDB.info`.

Answer (score 0):

can you please change your second line as below for database name

```
INTO TABLE dbname.info
```

replace dbname by the name of your database.